# TypeScript オブジェクトに関数を含む場合の型定義方法

Tags: javascript, typescript

下記のコードを型定義してTypeScriptにしてみたのですが、オブジェクトのプロパティに関数がある場合型をどのように定義したら良いか分からなくなりつまずきました。みて見ただけないでしょうか？

```
// ペンギンくん
var Penguin = {
    name: 'ペンギン',
};

// 鷹
var Falcon = {
    name: '鷹',
    fly: function(){
        console.log(this.name + 'が大空を飛びました');
    }
};

Falcon.fly();  // '鷹が大空を飛びました
```

自分で型を付けてみた。

```
// ペンギンくん
const Penguin : {
    name: string;
} = {
    name: 'ペンギン',
};

// 鷹
const Falcon : {
    name: string;
    fly: any;
} = {
    name: '鷹',
    fly: function(): void{
        console.log(this.name + 'が大空を飛びました');
    }
};

Falcon.fly();  // '鷹が大空を飛びました
```

#### 参照

https://qiita.com/39_isao/items/c00a200b158ba057363f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

関数の型 - TypeScript Deep Dive 日本語版#関数の宣言
https://typescript-jp.gitbook.io/deep-dive/type-system/functions#no

関数の型は `(引数の型) => 戻り値の型` のように書くので、今回のような引数がなくvoidを返すような関数の型は `() => void` になります。

```
// 鷹
const Falcon : {
    name: string;
    fly: () => void;
} = {
    name: '鷹',
    fly: function(): void {
        console.log(this.name + 'が大空を飛びました');
    }
};

Falcon.fly();  // '鷹が大空を飛びました
```

TS Playground

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=30&pln=8&pc=1#code/PTAEi2GRnhkOoZMeQZDJDAWAFAGMD2A7AzgF1AAUBTLAcwFcBLLUALlAG9VRXQsBDAW2IfwCcaZANyoAvqAC8TFm048GAciixFAGnGiUqEKECfuaky4CAMQ4AbI-Rko27br1AChWuwDNzATwYAKAJRSAHygAG4YVAAmWhLSzLZyDkp66rKsHt6gbhRYaHhU2P4MYZE2dnZGOBjmxAB05hhkPngAFlQ4NfLEoADUoIqAMgyA5JqAXl6ASQyA2xmAzgyAfgyA6gyA+gyKfq5sYpqoqGaW2DXp-sKsuop6Q2NTc-NAA